# How can I make put and delete requests from a form using node.js and express.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

So I'm trying to make a put request using

My put form

```
    <form id="for" action="/people" method="post">
        <div class="">
            <input type="text" name="Name" value=<%= data[0].name %> >
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <input type="text" name="City" value="" placeholder=<%= data[0].favorite_city %>>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put"/>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Edit">
    </form>
```

My server side scripts

```js
  var methodOverride = require('method-override');
  app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

    app.put('/people', function(req,res){
  pg.connect(DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done){
    var pid = parseInt(req.params.id);
    var name = req.query.Name;
    var city = req.query.City;
    var client_query = '';
    if(name = ''){
      client_query = `update persons set favorite_city =${city} where id = ${pid}`;
    }
    else{
      client_query = `update persons set name = ${name}, favorite_city= ${city} where id= ${pid}`;
    }
    client.query(client_query, function(err, result){
      res.redirect(`/people/${pid}`)
      done();
      pg.end();
    })
  })
});
```

I am using method override but it only seems to do a post with the new data
The problem is similar with delete so I'm not going to put the code here because it may be a little redundant. But if anyone wants to see it I don't mind

Answer (score 0):

`methodOverride('_method')` returns a middleware that looks for the key *_method* in the **query string** (see [method-override docs](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override#getter)). By including the *_method* variable in the form and sending the form with the POST method, *_method* is not included in the query string, but in the request body. Probably you want to use the body-parser middleware before the methodOverride middleware and then do something like:

```
app.use(methodOverride(req => req.body._method));
```

In addition, you probably want to replace `query` with `body` in:

```
var name = req.query.Name;
var city = req.query.City;
```

Comment: So I made your edits and it seems to direct me to http://localhost:3000/people/NaN and crashes the server I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You are using `req.params.id` which is not set. You need to change two things: (1) Add the id to the url of the HTML form: `action="/people/[insert id here]"`. (2) Add an id parameter to the express route: `app.put('/people/:id', ...`.